# How can you analyse a model which is both formative AND reflective?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I’ve had a student complete a piece of work with some great data. I am considering re-analysing the data for publication. SEM makes sense, but the model is both formative and reflective. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "formative" and "reflective"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Really good explanation found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184947/what-is-the-difference-between-formative-and-reflective-measurement-models

Comment: One example of a model with both kinds of indicator is a MIMIC model, see, for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189462/whats-the-difference-between-a-mimic-factor-and-a-composite-with-indicators-se But there's nothing special that you need to do - just put them both in.

Comment: Please clarify what "the issue" is here.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Miles, this is exactly what I was looking for :-D :-D